# tangents and bitangents or larger textures?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, normals, normal-mapping

This is more of a performance question than anything, but some time ago I learned that to put normal maps in OpenGL 3D rendering, I could do it in two ways... The first is generally what most people should do. is using tangent space and saving bitangent and tangent so that they can recalculate the direction of the normals according to the model, the second one that I generally knew existed but never thought much about is using object space, where the data of the 360 degrees of angle They are saved in the image at once and eliminate the need to save tangents and bitangents, but a question came to mind... Which one is smaller in terms of performance? Because I thought that maybe I could match the quality of space per object if I saved images with more than 256 bits per pixel, but then I also thought about this in terms of map size and came to a confusing impasse, which of these techniques would it perform better?

Comment: Object Space Normal maps only work when you don't deform the object (for example via Skinning). As soon as you consider deforming the object you need tangent space normal maps.

The performance is neglegible between the two.

Comment: `where the data of the 360 degrees of angle They are saved in the image at once and eliminate the need to save tangents and bitangents` I'm not sure I completely understand that. Would this technique work on a mesh that's more complex than a flat wall? Would it allow such a texture to be used on two meshes of different shapes ?

Comment: First for Raildex, I thought that if it were possible to pass the bone id information, influence weights and geometric transformation matrices from the vertex to the fragment, I could apply them to the normal map of the object's space so that the normals of the same were recalculated and the lighting worked without needing tangents and bitangents.

Comment: According to Tom Tsagkatos, images generally work by saving colors of 256 This allows 180 degrees of a flat space to be distributed in 180/256 = 0.7 degrees per pixel change, but in an object space they are generally 360 /256 = 1.4 degrees per pixel which means that images in the standard object space format tend to have more drastic and not as realistic light and shadow variation... I asked that if I use an image with one bit more to If the images had 512 as RGB standard, wouldn't that allow me to do away with tangent and bitangent without losing quality and having better performance?

Comment: Although Raildex seems to have answered the question about performance...